# Как создать парсер для консоли C#

Tags: c#, консоль, калькулятор

Пытаюсь создать парсер для консольного калькулятора, который будет принимать от пользователя два числа и знак арифметической операции, и проверять их на допустимость. В случае неправильно введенного значения - вывод исключения.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace MyCalc
{
    public static class Parser
    {
        public static Sign sign;
        public static void Parse()
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Введите первое число:");
                Calculation.firstNumber = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Введено неправильное значение!!!");
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Введите второе число:");
                Calculation.secondNumber = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Введено неправильное значение!!!");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Какую операцию желаете выполнить?\n1) +\n2) -\n3) *\n4) /");
            sign = (Sign)Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }
}
```

Но интересует вариант, чтобы в блоках try|catch не использовалось обращение к консоли. Может как-то с использованием интерфейсов можно брать значение у пользователей и передавать в try|catch ?

Comment: Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых чтение из консоли можно вынести из `try`/`catch`:

```
string firstNumberString = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Введите первое число:");

try
{
    Calculation.firstNumber = double.Parse(firstNumberString);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Введено неправильное значение!!!");
    return;
}
```

Во вторых, можно обойтись без исключений:

```
Console.WriteLine("Введите первое число:");

double firstNumber;
if (Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out firstNumber))
{
    Calculation.firstNumber = firstNumber;
}
else
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Введено неправильное значение!!!");
    return;
}
```

Интерфейсы как-то прикрутить ко всему этому, но для решения данной конкретной задачи они не нужны.

Comment: Спасибо. Решил сделать без исключений